# How to update old MVC app that extends Microsoft.Web.Mvc.DataAnnotations.DataAnnotationsModelBinder?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I'm updating an old ASP.NET MVC application to use the 4.0 framework, and I'm not sure what to do with the custom ModelBinders. They extend Microsoft.Web.Mvc.DataAnnotations.DataAnnotationsModelBinder, which seems not to exist in 4.0, and they are registered in global.asax.

What is the best way to implement specific binding validation rules? Should I continue to use a custom model binder? If so, what is the default binder I should subclass (or perhaps decorate)? Or should I create custom validation attributes instead? Or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I continue to use a custom model binder?

Impossible to say without explaining what your application does and why was this custom model binder needed before.

> If so, what is the default binder I should subclass (or perhaps decorate)?

The default model binder is: [`System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.defaultmodelbinder.aspx) which implements the [`IModelBinder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.imodelbinder.aspx) interface but you rarely have to directly implement the interface when creating a custom model binder as the default model binder already contains lots of functionality.

> Or should I create custom validation attributes instead?

If you are doing validation you could indeed create validation attributes deriving from [ValidationAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute.aspx) or some of the existing data annotations. Or if you are like me you could use [FluentValidation.NET](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/).

So, as you can  see it will all depend.